# Is there any philosophical English term close to greek aletheia/alethes ( ἀλήθεια/ α-ληθές)?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, terminology, truth

Aletheia means unveiled mystery, not secret, disclosed facts and intentions, how something works and how it does not work, how it does exist and how it does not exist.

"To say of what is that it is not, or of what is not that it is, is ψεῦδος, while to say of what is that it is, and of what is not that it is not, is αληθές" - Aristotle 1011b27

Martin Heidegger "To raise the question of aletheia, of disclosure as such, is not the same as raising the question of truth. For this reason, it was inadequate and misleading to call aletheia, in the sense of opening, truth."

"[ἀ–λήθεια](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/9208/is-there-a-sanskrit-term-that-overlaps-semantically-with-%E1%BC%80-%CE%BB%CE%AE%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1-a-letheia), uses the privative ἀ; letheia (λήθεια) is semantically connected to the Hadean river of forgetfulness lethe (λήθε), and of oblivion, it also underlies the Latin lateo, 'am hidden', 'remain unnoticed', from which English derives 'latent'.now the sanskrit vowel अ is related to the greek ἀ, and is also used as a privative in Sanskrit."

Are there any other (philosopher's) works about the term except that of Heidegger?

Comment: The contrast with pseudo is interesting. But it evokes "fake" and "true" to me, which doesn't seem to be quite like "un-mistery, un-secret and un-closed". That would be more like "open", as in the expression an "open secret".

Comment: open facts do not give clean open intentions, that is why unclosed not same is open. Unclosed mean something without inner borders, open means you have to enter to make the rules work - not enter no work. second is like contract with devil, you follow by rules, rules are open, but game is unfair. Unclosed mean opened inside, opened outside. Do you know that concept of Paradis gates are different: some opened outside, some inside?

Comment: Sounds like Trojan Horse. It's revealed but at the same time not what it appears to be.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aletheia

Comment: @estinamir no-no. The question: is it a horse?  - the truth variant: yes, it is a horse. - aletheia: no, it is military squad inside the horse!

That is a different.

Comment: [Theory and History of Ontology](https://www.ontology.co/aletheia.htm) has a helpful survey of the studies of the use of *ἀλήθεια* in ancient Greek with a number of references. Heidegger's musings have more to do with his own interests than with the original meaning.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know Ancient Greeks had Alexa helping them :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Alexa#:~:text=Amazon%20developers%20chose%20the%20name,Internet%20for%20the%20same%20reason.

Comment: aletheia is uncovering

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of *unveiled* and *disclosure*, the later also appearing in the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aletheia#:%7E:text=%C9%99%2F%3B%20Ancient%20Greek%3A%20%E1%BC%80%CE%BB%CE%AE%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1,from%20common%20conceptions%20of%20truth.) article about Heidegger and aletheia.

With respect to philosophers, after Heidegger more have discussed it, usually calling it [*World disclosure*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_disclosure):

> It has been discussed (not always using the same name) by philosophers such as **John Dewey, Jürgen Habermas, Nikolas Kompridis and Charles Taylor**.

Comment: Thank you for fixing, but term disclosure needed that something was closed, but aletheia means that the world is not closed, but the mind can be closed or be in sleeping. So, truth concept became after "the contract", if someone is following the contract you call this truth, if not lie.  Aletheia in this system is a state of nature, not the contract, and not something after contract. For example - Fire is hot, if the fire is not hot it is not Fire, it is pseudo-fire - picture of the fire, image, word "fire" and else, but not Fire or pure idea. And more, to understand what is Hot - touch Fire.

Comment: @άνθρωπος You're right, the closest we can get in English is disclosed I think, although it's not as precise as aletheia, since not closed presumes that it *could be* closed, whereas aletheia is more in the lines of something that was *hiding in plain sight*, but never closed or unreachable. That's why I personally prefer *unveiled* because it reminds that it is the *observer* the one who lifts their own veil so that they can *see the truth*. But it seems from Wikipedia that *disclosed* won.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are different ways to search for the meaning of a term:

   - One way is etymology: That's what Heidegger did – splitting the word    as ἀ–λήθεια. Now the word becomes an invitation for further
     speculation
   - A second way is to ask a native speaker how the word is used at that time. Here we have Aristotle with the quote above. Aristotle
     equates     ἀληθές = true - without much ado.

   Heidegger criticizes how Aristotle uses the word. Quite remarkable
   for a non-native speaker belonging  to a different culture and from
   the distance of more than 2.000 years! How useful is          Heidegger’s
   explanation from etymology?
2. Unfortunately I do not know who followed Heidegger. I would look
   around to his direct German students like Broecker and Gadamer.
3. Sanskrit does not construct “truth” as a negation. Here "sat = being,
   true" is the participle of “to be”.
   I consider it an interesting
   linguistic question to compare the word “true” in all
   Indo-European languages.

Comment: "That's what Heidegger did – splitting the word as ἀ–λήθεια." Yes, he does that. But then ignores the fact that lethe is the river of forgetfulness and oblivion, which he never mentions among the various other quasi-equivalents that he does discuss. That seems very odd, though not quite arbitrary to me.

Comment: "Aristotle equates ἀληθές = true" - why did you think so? When you are checking is something a true, you do not say that it is be, you say it is equal to that etalon or it is an abstract noun, you say. So you are saying the true to a reference to something else, not to this that does exist or has an existence.

Comment: When you are saying about woman, for example, you will not say this is a woman, you will say that is a woman because she identified while born as a woman, so, she is biological woman - that you should to say. This word biological have primary sense, when you are assigning a woman meaning to saying. So you answer that is biological, and then a woman. The word woman become senseless out of biological view or category... And you still can't answer what is a woman, or who is a woman. Aristotle had not the biology or the social(adjective) as a separate cat, cause "what" quest is already a category

Comment: @άνθρωπος I mean "Aristotle equates ἀληθές = true" due to your quote from Aristotle. – In antique Greek “einai” can also mean “to be true”. See “Charles H. Kahn: The Greek Verb 'To Be' and the Concept of Being. Foundations of Language , Aug., 1966, Vol. 2, No. 3 (Aug., 1966), pp. 245-265”. It’s the same as in Sanskrit.

Comment: Look, Aristotle said, that there are three kinds of names: equivocal names - when something called equal, but not different in logos(context, discourse), for example a cow being and a cow image - both are cows, but different is logos sense; second kind is univocally - that are sounds same and do-be same - leaving creatures - cat and dog are leaving creatures - univocally... so okey, you say that word readed equivocally. But as you see, even Aristotle's aletheia has more then true equal sing: ...and of what is not that it is not.

Comment: @JoWehler So when you are looking at equivocal names, thay also must be not contradicting them own self. That mean the woman can not be a man - because they are in converse positions. Woman the who is a woman, but also woman is not man - i read the dichotomy in Aristotle phrase. The sense, that to say the woman is a woman - is not enough, because, you must to name also who is not a woman - in logos or discourse sense, not in vocal or lettering image only. So when you say the "Aristotle equates ἀληθές = true" - that is "half-true")